# wxFileDialog open in MyApp::OnInit() error

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I am trying to open a wxFileDialog in MyApp::OnInit(), but I end up with an error message saying **"no matching function for call to ‘wxFileDialog::wxFileDialog(MyApp* const, const char [12], const wxChar*&, const wxChar*&, const char [6], )"**.

```
MyApp::OnInit()
{
    wxFileDialog dialog2(this, _T("open a file"), wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString, _T("*.csv"), wxFD_OPEN);
    dialog2.ShowModal();
    ... open the file and then do something ...
}
```

The idea is to allow the user to open a config file before the program starts. Can anyone offer some advice to this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your first parameter, the dialog parent, it expects a `wxWindow*` but you are passing a `MyApp*`. Since you don't have a parent just pass `NULL` instead.

```
wxFileDialog dialog2(NULL, _T("open a file"), wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString, _T("*.csv"), wxFD_OPEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [wxWidgets documenation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.3/group__group__funcmacro__string.html#ga8a02b8875a521df57263a9e6f090f2d0), the macro `_T()` is different from `_()`. So, try just with `_`  while passing the arguments.

```
wxFileDialog dialog2(this, 
                     _("open a file"), 
                     wxEmptyString,
                     wxEmptyString,
                     _("*.csv"), 
                     wxFD_OPEN);
```